# Netbeans plugins for development in magento 2

Tags: magento2, plugin

Does anyone know what are the best netbeans plugins to develop in magento 2? It would be very useful to have a list of the best plugins and to know what they do, since I haven't found a guide on google that explains everything step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately it depends what you will be working on and working with.

For example if using git I found Git toolbar plugin really useful

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/51604/git-toolbar

Useful to know line endings

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/36810/show-and-change-line-endings

But in truth I switched from using netbeans to using vscode. I found netbeans too slow when working on Magento 2 projects.  Especially when it started to scan files for code completion hints (or whatever they call it).  I did a load of tweaks to make netbeans faster but eventually I made the switch.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the plugins but definitely, you can use the power of macros.
In the past, I have used the macros for faster development in Magento 1
https://blog.magepsycho.com/using-netbeans-macros-to-speed-up-magento-templating/

Maybe, you can use the same concept but for Magento2.